# Как сделать, чтобы пользователь после заполнения формы не смог попасть на эту страницу?

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы пользователь после заполнения формы на веб странице и нажатия на кнопку дальше не мог попасть назад на эту страницу после заполнения формы?

Comment: при желании можно попасть туда где однаждыпобывал браузер))
вам ето зачем нада? возможно есть другие пути решения

Answer (score 1):

Задача достаточно стандартная, например тест. Ответив на вопрос назад перейти нельзя.
Решается просто, в сессию пишем текущий статус пользователя, например вопрос #5 и выдаём соответствующий контент, при этом для всех вопросов URL будет одна и таже.

Вывод, что бы решить поставленную задачу используйте сессии.

Comment: Можно пример с кодом.Спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Запускаем сессию
session_start();
// Допустим юзер нажал далее, на этой странице пишем
$_SESSION['page'] = 2 // Номер страницы;
// На предыдушей странице пишем:
if($_SESSION['page'] !=2)
{
  //Выводим страницу
}
else
{
 header("location: page2.php"); // Если юзер побывал на второй странице, то на первую зайти не получится
}
```